# node express, why it comes up with undefined?

Tags: javascript

```html
router.get('/like', isLoggedIn, async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        console.log("req = ", req.user.id);
        const [bo] = await Promise.all([
            Who.findAll({ where: { liked: req.user.id  } }),
        ]);
        // const bo = await Who.findAll({ where: { liked: req.user.id } });
        console.log("@!@@!@@@@ ", bo.thisbook);
        const books = await Book.findAll({ where: { id: bo.thisbook } });
        res.render('likedProduct.html', {
            books,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        next(error);
    }
});
```

-----terminal------

req =  1

@!@@!@@@@  undefined

why does it come up with undefined? even if there are information in databases

Comment: Maybe `Who.findAll` returns an array and arrays don't have a `thisbook` property so you get undefined? Maybe `bo[0]?.thisbook` gets you what you're after?

Comment: thanks!!! but how do I get whole information from the array?

Comment: This isn't the place to learn the fundamentals of javascript arrays.